# Laravel Redirect::to from ajax post with success message

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

How we know `Redirect::to` not working in Controller if it's called by ajax.

Then we need to redirect from ajax callback with

`window.location.replace("{{ URL::to('link') }}");`

or just link if we are not in blade

`window.location.replace("link");`

But what to do if I need to redirect with message? Usually i would do it like this:

`return Redirect::to('link')->with('success','Success message' );`

Comment: flash your message using session::flash and redirect with ajax. Flashed data is available for the next `HTTP_REQUEST`

Comment: @mdamia Thanks for you help!